# max execution time different from what I set

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a php script that stores a large amount of data from an excel file into a mysql-DB.

I'm getting a **"max execution time of 500 seconds"** error even if I can't find where this limit has been set.

php.ini has `max_execution_time = 1800` (as shown from phpinfo()) and there's no other php file where I accidentally put something like `set_time_limit(500)`

Where could this '500' limit be?

Comment: Is this a web page or a PHP CLI script. There are normally 2 different `php.ini` file, one for each environment

Comment: If web page run a page with just `<?php phpinfo();?>` and check the output for where the ini file lives. If PHP CLI run `>php --ini` and check the output for where the ini file lives

Comment: It could also be from your hosting. They might have some limitations by monitoring the script runtime.

Comment: It's a web page, phpinfo tells me that "Loaded Configuration File" is  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini . In this file I have max_execution_time = 1800